# extracting key-value pairs from a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

I have dictionary in the following format stored inside a list.Below are listed the 12 members (dictionaries) of list `switch_ports`

```
[
{'type': 'port', 'number': 1, 'port_state': 1, 'state': 'active', 'port_id': '00:00:00:00:00:00:02:011', 'desc': 's1-eth1'},
{'type': 'port', 'number': 2, 'port_state': 1, 'state': 'active', 'port_id': '00:00:00:00:00:00:02:012', 'desc': 's1-eth2'},
{'type': 'port', 'number': 1, 'port_state': 1, 'state': 'active', 'port_id': '00:00:00:00:00:00:02:021', 'desc': 's2-eth1'},
{'type': 'port', 'number': 2, 'port_state': 1, 'state': 'active', 'port_id': '00:00:00:00:00:00:02:022', 'desc': 's2-eth2'},
{'type': 'port', 'number': 1, 'port_state': 1, 'state': 'active', 'port_id': '00:00:00:00:00:00:02:031', 'desc': 's3-eth1'},
{'type': 'port', 'number': 2, 'port_state': 1, 'state': 'active', 'port_id': '00:00:00:00:00:00:02:032', 'desc': 's3-eth2'},
{'type': 'port', 'number': 1, 'port_state': 1, 'state': 'active', 'port_id': '00:00:00:00:00:00:02:041', 'desc': 's4-eth1'},
{'type': 'port', 'number': 2, 'port_state': 1, 'state': 'active', 'port_id': '00:00:00:00:00:00:02:042', 'desc': 's4-eth2'},
{'type': 'port', 'number': 1, 'port_state': 1, 'state': 'active', 'port_id': '00:00:00:00:00:00:02:051', 'desc': 's5-eth1'},
{'type': 'port', 'number': 2, 'port_state': 1, 'state': 'active', 'port_id': '00:00:00:00:00:00:02:052', 'desc': 's5-eth2'},
{'type': 'port', 'number': 1, 'port_state': 1, 'state': 'active', 'port_id': '00:00:00:00:00:00:02:061', 'desc': 's6-eth1'},
{'type': 'port', 'number': 2, 'port_state': 1, 'state': 'active', 'port_id': '00:00:00:00:00:00:02:062', 'desc': 's6-eth2'}]
```

From the list `switch_ports` I want to access `port_id` above. How do I do that?

If I do

```
for port in switch_ports:
      print(port)
```

I get the same output as above. However If I try to access individual key-value pairs as below.

```
for port in switch_ports:
      print(port[port_id])
```

How do I get the `port_id`  (e.g `00:00:00:00:00:00:02:062`) from the list `switch_ports`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Just use `port_id` as a string, like this

```
for port in switch_ports:
      print(port["port_id"])
```

If you want to gather all the `port_id`s as a list, then use list comprehension like this

```
port_ids = [port["port_id"] for port in switch_ports]
```

[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/O7rqbM)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, use `itemgetter` from the `operator` module:

```
>>> import operator
>>> operator.itemgetter('port_id')
<operator.itemgetter object at 0x7f318d7b8b90>
>>> port_id = operator.itemgetter('port_id')
>>> for port in switch_ports:
...     print port_id(port)
...
```

prints:

```
00:00:00:00:00:00:02:011
00:00:00:00:00:00:02:012
00:00:00:00:00:00:02:021
00:00:00:00:00:00:02:022
00:00:00:00:00:00:02:031
00:00:00:00:00:00:02:032
00:00:00:00:00:00:02:041
00:00:00:00:00:00:02:042
00:00:00:00:00:00:02:051
00:00:00:00:00:00:02:052
00:00:00:00:00:00:02:061
00:00:00:00:00:00:02:062
```